# VB.net Merging Duplicate class items into a list

Tags: vb.net

I have a class of variables. To keep it simple I will use car stock as an example. So in my class I have variables for say:-

```
Car Manufacturer
Car Colour
Car Quantity
```

and my class looks something like this.. (but potential for hundreds of lines)

```
BMW, Black, 2
Mercedes, White, 1
Honda, Green, 3
BMW, Red, 1
```

I need to create a list that merges the manufacturer and the quantity but separates the colours e.g. new list should look something like:-

```
BMW, 3
Black
Red
Mercedes, 1
White
Honda, 3
Green
```

Can someone help explain the best way to go about this please?

Comment: its hard to make sense of the question without a clearer picture of the Car class (not even sure that is the name of the class)

Comment: Would it help if I said Car was the class and the variables would then be: car.manufacturer, car.colour & car.qty ? Final list would be new list(of string) called stocklist. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't hate one-liners and have some idea of how LINQ works, the following expression will return an array of `Tuple(Of String, Integer)` where `Item1` will have the name of manufacturer and `Item2` will have the total number of their cars:

```
YourCarsList.GroupBy(Function(r) r.Manufacturer).Select(Function(r) New Tuple(Of String, Integer)(r.Key, r.Sum(Function(r2) r2.Quantity))).ToArray()
```

Note that the output you have shown in the question is *console-ish* and cannot be returned in that form by a function or expression. If you really want to just print this as text output, you could extend the above expression like this:

```
Dim Res = YourCarsList.GroupBy(Function(r) r.Manufacturer)

For Each R In Res
    output.AppendLine(R.Key, r.Sum(Function(r) r.Quantity))

    For Each Clr In R.Select(Function(r) r.Colour).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(r) r)
        output.AppendLine(Clr)
    Next 
Next
```